# ScaLapack installation fails with its auto installer package on Centos7 but it succeeds on Centos 6.7. Why?

Tags: gcc, mpi, centos7, gfortran, scalapack

I am trying to install the ScaLAPACK with the help of Python-based installer available at http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/scalapack_installer.tgz on CentOS 7(64bit). It is installing successfully but failing in test routines step and showing the error. how to fix it?

**The command used for the compilation is as follows:**

```
./setup.py --prefix=/home/tools/scalapack --blaslib="-L/usr/lib64 -lblas" --lapacklib="-L/usr/lib64 -llapack -lblas" --mpiincdir=/opt/apps/mpich32/include --fcflags="-fbounds-check" --mpirun=mpirun --mpicc=mpicc --mpif90=mpif90
```

**The process description is as follows**

```
Installing  scalapack-2.0.2 ...
Writing SLmake.inc... done.
Compiling BLACS, PBLAS and ScaLAPACK... done
Getting ScaLAPACK version number... 2.0.1
Installation of ScaLAPACK successful.
(log is in  /home/tools/scalapack_installer/build/log/scalog )
Compiling test routines... done
Running BLACS test routines... done
Running PBLAS test routines... 

PBLAS: error running PBLAS test routines xcpblas2tst

PBLAS: Command mpirun -np 4 ./xcpblas2tst
stderr:
**************************************** 
At line 1 of file ctzpad.f
Fortran runtime error: Actual string length is shorter than the declared one for dummy argument 'herm' (-960965440/1)
```